# sending http request return <>

Tags: ios

i have tried to make login form to check Username & Password from external server using http request but the response is given <>

```
- (IBAction)getlogin:(UIButton *)sender {
    NSString *rawStrusername = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@",_username.text];
    NSString *rawStrpassword = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"password=%@",_password.text];

    NSString *post = @"rawStrusername&rawStrpassword";
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
   /*
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];*/
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.othaimmarkets.com/my_services_path/user/login"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    /*[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];*/
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];



    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", responseData);
}
```

any help, suggestions or examples would be appreciated

Comment: If the server is returning incorrect replies to correct requests, it's probably a server issue.

Comment: i tested the server through plugin for firefox {Poster} and return me result 
URL:http://www.othaimmarkets.com/my_services_path/user/login (OR http://www.othaimmarkets.com/my_services_path/user/login.json)

Content Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Name: username
Value: mohammed.abdelrasoul@gmail.com
Name: password
Value: 29378960
Actions: POST

Comment: Then check the result you're sending to help you debugging.

Comment: am new to ios can you described more clear plz

Comment: If iOS doesn't support logging the HTTP traffic, you should be able route the traffic through [an HTTP proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) running on your PC.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *post = @"rawStrusername&rawStrpassword";
```

You are sending the "`rawStrusername&rawStrpassword`" string to the server? Why don't you try with:

```
NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@&%@", rawStrusername, rawStrpassword];
```

Comment: i trid it it gives me responseData: <6e756c6c>

Comment: This is binary data. Convert it to string to see the real response. `NSLog(@"responseData: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);`

Comment: Mohammed Abdelrasoul, if you liked this answer, please mark it as correct, and optionally give it an up vote. Welcome to SO.